# Twisted Reactor not Restartable - Using asynchronous threading repeatedly

Tags: multithreading, twisted, reactor

I have a list of URLs. I want to get their content asynchronously every 10 seconds.

```
urls = [
 'http://www.python.org', 
 'http://stackoverflow.com', 
 'http://www.twistedmatrix.com', 
 'http://www.google.com',
 'http://launchpad.net',
 'http://github.com',
 'http://bitbucket.org',
]

waiting = [client.getPage(url) for url in urls]
defer.gatherResults(waiting).addCallback(saveResults)

reactor.run()
```

How do I do this? This code allows me to only get the urls content once. Calling it again throws `error.ReactorNotRestartable()`

Thanks :)

Comment: There are no threads in this example.  Did you intent to include some?

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible with Twisted.

First off, although this is somewhat unrelated to your question, don't use `getPage`.  It's a very limited API, with poor defaults for security on HTTPS. Instead, use [Treq](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/treq).

Now, onto your main question.

The important thing to understand about `reactor.run()` is that it doesn't mean "run this code here".  It means "run the whole program".  When `reactor.run()` exits, it's time for your program to exit.

Lucky for you, Twisted has a nice built-in way to do things on a regular schedule: [`LoopingCall`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html).

Here's a working example, using `treq` and `LoopingCall`:

```
urls = [
    'http://www.python.org',
    'http://stackoverflow.com',
    'http://www.twistedmatrix.com',
    'http://www.google.com',
    'http://launchpad.net',
    'http://github.com',
    'http://bitbucket.org',
]

from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
from twisted.internet.defer import gatherResults
from treq import get, content

def fetchWebPages():
    return (gatherResults([get(url).addCallback(content) for url in urls])
            .addCallback(saveResults))

def saveResults(responses):
    print("total: {} bytes"
          .format(sum(len(response) for response in responses)))


repeatedly = LoopingCall(fetchWebPages)
repeatedly.start(10.0)

from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.run()
```

As a bonus, this handles the case where `fetchWebPages` takes longer than 10 seconds, and will react intelligently rather than letting too many outstanding requests pile up, or delaying longer and longer as the requests take longer.